# Why do I receive an error "size is missing in 'grades'. When row is apparently not necessary to declare?

Tags: arrays, c, row

Going over a tutorial for two dimensional arrays. Tutorial says no need to define the row in the two dimensional array. Their code runs fine and returns "89" as expected. Mine complains about missing size for grades[][columns]

Any ideas?

````
int main () 
{

    int const columns = 3;
    int grades[][columns] = {
        {12, 23, 45},
        {64, 78, 89}
    };

    printf("%d", grades[1][2]);
  return 0;
}```




Output: error: array size missing in 'grades'
    8 |     int grades[][columns] = {
````

Comment: Is the tutorial you're using C++ or C? That's perfectly valid C++ but not C.

Comment: That's confusing. The tutorial is specifically for C and works fine for the guy writing the program?

Comment: @WhozCraig It's not VLA support, VLAs can't be initialized in any version of the C standard.

Comment: It's pretty common on some platforms to compile C-ish code with a C++ compiler, are you sure that's not what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler error isn't related to the empty brackets, it's the `columns` that's the problem. You can't initialize an array that's sized by a variable (these are called variable length arrays, or VLAs for short).

This would work fine, for example:

```
#define COLUMNS 3

int main () 
{
    int grades[][COLUMNS] = {
        {12, 23, 45},
        {64, 78, 89}
    };

    printf("%d", grades[1][2]);
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is trying to tell you that, since you can't initialize a variable-sized array, you need to provide both array bounds and then fill the array after its declaration.